# How can I keep columns from wrapping into a single column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a site using **Bootstrap 3.1.1**. The `body` tag has a `min-width` of 800px.

The data I am attempting to display needs to appear in a grid. It's a representation of a parking lot.

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve (at least for right now). This is how the data appears when my window is larger than a certain point (I am not sure what width my browser is at when it works/doesn't).

[image: good]

and this is (a portion) of what happens when the windows is too small:

[image: bad]

Part of the reason this is a fixed width site in the first place is because I need to display this. How can I use bootstrap for it's grid layout, but keep the columns from wrapping?

Here's how I am trying to group the data:

```
<div class="row" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="col-xs-1"> <!-- a single row, e.g. 392-337 -->
        <div class="col-xs-6 pull-left"> <!-- the numbers on the left hand side, 392-365 -->
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                392
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                391
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                390
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                389
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                388
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                387
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                386
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                385
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                384
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                383
            </div>
        </div><div class="col-xs-6 pull-right"> <!-- numbers on the right hand side, 364-337 -->
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                364
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                363
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                362
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                361
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                360
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                359
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                358
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                357
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                356
            </div><div class="col-xs-12">
                355
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`col-xs-1` won't allow for two wide in the column, it's too skinny.  Change `div class="col-xs-1"` to `div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"` or if you want custom widths than add your own custom % widths.

I don't think you need all of the other `col-xs-12` either since that is adding extra padding.

**[Bootply with fixes](http://www.bootply.com/ZtUrPAvqIA)**

Or if you want the columns to be closer together then use `col-xs-4` instead of `col-xs-6`, just make sure you create a new `<div class="row">` before moving on to the next column ([Bootply with that example here](http://www.bootply.com/dKznF5nhNV#))

Updated HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"> <!-- a single row, e.g. 392-337 -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"> <!-- the numbers on the left hand side, 392-365 -->
            <div>392</div>
            <div>391</div>
            <div>390</div>
            <div>389</div>
            <div>388</div>
            <div>387</div>
            <div>386</div>
            <div>385</div>
            <div>384</div>
            <div>383</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"> <!-- numbers on the right hand side, 364-337 -->
            <div>364</div>
            <div>363</div>
            <div>362</div>
            <div>361</div>
            <div>360</div>
            <div>359</div>
            <div>358</div>
            <div>357</div>
            <div>356</div>
            <div>355</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first example (`col-xs-2 col-md-1`) works well enough that I feel comfortable moving forward - however. There is a still one brief moment that it still collapses the columns, but it corrects itself when I make the window smaller. Any idea why there is a weird area where it collapses the columns?

Comment: Whoops - I was wrong. I just missed the extra row you added in there. Still having one problem though - anything I can do about my rows totaling more than 12 when `col-xs-2` is active? When that is triggered, it wraps the final columns.

Comment: You mean that there are more than 6 columns of col-xs-2? You could try making the fonts smaller, but at a certain point it's going to be so condensed that it won't be worth looking at on a small screen.